# Azure Data Sync and Triggers

Tags: sql, azure, triggers, azure-data-sync

I use SQL Azure Data Sync to sync my remote Azure database with my local SQL database. Data Sync does create some addional tables on client and server and also adds delete, insert and update triggers to existing tables.

For what are these triggers? Can i delete them? I don't think so?

Problem now is that i can't edit data on server.

I get the error

```
The target table 'dbo.Corporation' of the DML statement cannot have any 
enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.
```

Comment: Found any solution? Having the same problem ...

Comment: not sure, i don't use data sync any more

Answer (score 1):

The triggers are added by the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx), which is being used for SQL Azure Data Sync. And, yes you can't delete them, because the SQL Azure Data Sync will stop working. It is not that easy to modify tables after they are provisioned. If you are adding columns check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285307/sync-framework-and-add-columns). If it is something else, just try searching solution to your project tagged under Microsoft sync framework and not SQL Azure.